# negative values in the writableraster

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage, raster

I'm trying to implement averaging filter with different sizes 3x3 , 5x5 , 7x7 and 11x11 .. I did the calculations and the results are correct while debugging but the problem is that it is saved in the writable raster in negative, so I'm getting weird results. The second weird thing is that when I want to get the value of the same pixel that was saved in negative, it is retrieved with positive value !! 
I'm using int.
What's wrong? any help ?!!

Here is my code for the 5x5 averaging filter.

```
   public static BufferedImage filter5x5_2D(BufferedImage paddedBI , BufferedImage bi , double[][]filter)
{

    WritableRaster myImage = paddedBI.copyData(null);
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    WritableRaster myImage2 = img.copyData(null);

    for(int i =2; i< myImage.getHeight()-2; i++)
        {
            for(int j =2; j< myImage.getWidth()-2; j++)
            {
                int value = 0;
                int copyi = i-2;
                for (int m = 0 ; m<5 ;  m++)
                {   
                    int copyj = j-2;
                    for (int n = 0; n<5; n++)
                    {
                        int result = myImage.getSample(copyj , copyi, 0);
                        double f = filter[m][n];
                        double add = result * filter[m][n];
                        value += (int) (filter[m][n] * myImage.getSample(copyj , copyi, 0));    
                        copyj ++;
                    }
                    copyi++;
                    //myImage2.setSample(j-1 , i-1, 0, value);
                }

                myImage2.setSample(j-2 , i-2, 0, value);
                //int checkResult = myImage2.getSample(j-1,i-1,0);
            }       
        }
    BufferedImage res= new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(),bi.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    res.setData(myImage2);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Java `byte`s (like all Java integral types) are signed. Using `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` you will have `byte` values, ranging from -128...127. Mask off the sign with `byteValue & 0xff` to have values in range 0...255.

Answer (score 0):

I do not find any negative values. Here is my main with what I have tested this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Tmp/test.bmp")); 

    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth()+4, bi.getHeight()+4, bi.getType());

    Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0,0,bi.getWidth()+4,bi.getHeight()+4);
    g.drawImage(bi, 2, 2, null);
    g.dispose();

    double[][] filter = new double[5][5];
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        for( int j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
            filter[i][j] = 1.0/(5*5);
        }
    }
    BufferedImage filtered = filter5x5_2D(newImage, bi, filter);
    ImageIO.write(filtered, "bmp", new File("C:/tmp/filtered.bmp"));
}
```

You should consider that your variables `result`, `f` and `add` are unused. Also it would be better if `value` would be of type `double` instead of `int`. In a worst case, you would get 25 times a value of 11 which will be rounded to zero after multiplying with 1/25. This would result in your code as a grey value of zero while it should result in 11.